# jquery resizable snap to div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-resizable

I have one or more draggable resizables in a `div` container. They already snap to the edges of the `div` when I drag them, but I also need them to snap to the edges when I resize them. In an extension I found, they only snap to other resizable, not to a certain `div`. Is there any extension for this issue?

Another problem is when I add `aspectRatio: true` to my resizable, I can't resize it anymore when it's dragged to the edge of the `div`, when it snapped...
update: you can now test it and see in the snippet. So I want to solve this and add resizable snap to it.

Some piece of code:

```js
$( ".resizable" ).resizable({ 
 containment: "#pagecontainer",
    aspectRatio: true,
 /*snap: "#pagecontainer",  this doesn't work */
 handles: 'n, s, e, w, nw, ne, se, sw'
});

$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
 containment: "#pagecontainer", 
 snap: "#pagecontainer", 
 scroll: false
});
```

```css
.resizable {
 position: absolute;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}
#pagecontainer {
 position: relative;
 border: 2px solid #ccc;
 padding: 0px;
 float: left;
 background-color: White;
    width: 500px; 
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="pagecontainer">
  <div id="photoframe1" class="draggable resizable droppable frame ui-widget-content ui-state-active">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think we can help you if you don't give as at least some minimal example of your code. A JsFiddle or something similar would be ideal of course

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> In an extension I found

Is it this one? [polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension](https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension)

and as you said:

> They only snap to other resizable, not to a certain div.

When you load that extension you can set the div you want to snap to easily like this example

```
$('.resize).resizable({
    snap: '#cenrtainDiv'
});
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want resizable div to snap to the container based on the resize direction then you might need to write your code inside the resize property of the resizable widget as shown below.

```
$( ".resizable" ).resizable({ 
    containment: "#pagecontainer",
    handles: 'n, s, e, w, nw, ne, se, sw',
    resize: function(e, ui) {
      //Based on the direction get the current position of the ui object while resizing
      var curPos = ui.position.left + ui.size.width; //This is for east handle

      //As given in the css for #pageContainer
      var containerWidth = 500; 

      //distance between the current position and the container width for snapping
      var dist = containerWidth - curPos;

      //Snap tolerance is 20px. It can be changed to any number for snapping to happen        
      if(dist > -20 && dist < 20) {
        $('.resizable').css('width', ui.size.width + dist);
      } 
    }
});
```

Let me know if this solution works for you. Although, you might want to write your own logic for other directions inside the resize function as I just did for east direction being resized.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Polomoshnov's solution only snaps to a div, not to the coordinates of a div (for example, it would snap to the left position of a div under the said div). Also, the code is a tad illegible, at least for me.  I tried to read into it, but maybe I am not too knowledgeable in this arena to make it do what it needs to do.